# How to fork SNMP trap packets using Perl?

Tags: perl, snmp, packet-sniffers, packet-injection

I have a need to receive SNMP traps and forward them to four different trap collection servers. SNMP traps are stateless UDP so I'm thinking it should be fairly easy to do...

I'm thinking perl is the way to go...

For each packet the tool would need to:

- Create a copy of the original packet
- Forge the source IP to match the original packet so the trap collector sees the correct source IP rather than the tool server's source IP
- re-send the packet to the trap collector

ASCII flow diagram:

Device -> toolServer -> collector1, collector2, collector3, collector4

suggestions? Does this seem feasible?